# React make web app chat work for mobile as well

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component for my chat in my small web app. It has 2 child components `ChatHistory`, `ChatMessages`, first it for displaying all chats with other users and the latter is for messages.

```
export default function Chat() {
  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <ChatHistory />
      <ChatMessages />
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the web version it works as expected, list of chats on left, and conversation on the right side. But now I want to make it work for mobile as well. Therefore I would like to first display `ChatHistory` and when user selects a chat, they will be redirected to `ChatMessages` of that chat room. It is a bit tricky since I want to figure out how to pass props from one another between these components. Also I have been thinking about separating them in different routes when on mobile, something like `/chats` and `/converstations`. I hope that someone could explain on what to do here or maybe provide something that you help me since I do not know how to search for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I get what you are asking lets hope this will help you.

#### Step 1:

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

#### Step 2: Create components

```
// Chat Component
function Chat() {
  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <ChatHistory />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// Chat History Component with some dummy history
function ChatHistory() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const histories = [
    { username: "user1", id: 1 },
    { username: "user2", id: 2 },
    { username: "user3", id: 3 },
    { username: "user4", id: 4 },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {histories.map((hist) => {
        return (
          <h1 key={hist.id} onClick={() => history.push(`/${hist.id}`)}>
            {hist.username}
          </h1>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// Chat message Component
function ChatMessages() {
  const { chatId } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to chat id: {chatId}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### The Main Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, useParams, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:chatId">
            <ChatMessages />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Chat />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Try to follow this code, Let's hope it will help you. Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing, on web use `react-router-dom`, use `react-native-router` on if you want to use routing on react native application. I don't know if this can help but please if you don't understand what im saying tell me i will show you by example what i mean

Comment: but I am not using react native and I am not making a mobile application, I am just using React for my web app and I want to make it friendly for mobile users as well.